# Horizontal sliding photos

Tags: html, css

It's doing my head in, I've been searching on Google the whole evening. I want all images lined up next to each other and a scrollbar so I can scroll (horizontal), like on this [site](http://jamesjoyce.co.uk/)
I'm using Drupal and on this [page](http://erlinevanhijfte.be/portret-studio#) I'm trying to do same but it's not working. I can't get them next to each other. It's probably something very simple but I'm not seeing it. I thought it would be:

```
.view-portret-studio{ overflow-x:scroll }
.view-portet-studio img{ display:inline-block }
```

Something along those lines, I also don't want to give a static width as I don't know how many pictures will be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
.view-portet-studio img{ float: left; }

Answer (score 0):

your referred link uses table structure to have a side by side structure.
use the same.
put all your .views-row div's inside td of same tr of table which is inside .view-content div.........:)

```
<div class="view-content">
<table><tr>
<td><div class="views-row ...">...</div></td>
<td><div class="views-row ...">...</div></td>
<td><div class="views-row ...">...</div></td>
<td><div class="views-row ...">...</div></td>
</tr></table></div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but I can't seem to get the images next to each other. When the images are smaller they'll get next to each other, but not all of them, probably something to do with the width

Comment: you have modified your original webpage and now you are using scroll to display them horizontally.
can you please create a plunker of your original html and i will make it show images horizontally.
as you modified your webpage, i dont have anything to work on.